# Named set vs 'grouped set' in MDX

Tags: ssas, mdx

To get a named set, for example the years between 2015-2018 (four values -- 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018) I can do:

```
WITH set [2015-2018] as {[Season].[Season].[Season].&[2015]:[Season].[Season].[Season].&[2018]}
SELECT {
        [Measures].[Wins]
} ON COLUMNS, {
    [2015-2018]

} ON ROWS
FROM [Nfl2]
```

And it gives me:

```
        Wins
2015    256
2016    254
2017    256
2018    254
```

How would I create a **single** grouped set (or whatever it is termed in MDX) where I could do the following:

```
            Wins
2015        256
2016        254
2017        256
2018        254
2015-2018   1020   *** how to do this in mdx?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Mdx we don't say Grouped set, but members, your aim is to create a member that holds the sum of wins from 2015 to 2018. In order to achieve that you need to specify an aggregation function for the calculated member [2015-2018] like this:

```
WITH 
Member [Season].[Season].[All].[2015-2018] AS SUM({[Season].[Season].&[2015]:[Season].[Season].&[2018]})
set [2015-2018-All] as {[Season].[Season].&[2015]:[Season].[Season].&[2018],[2015-2018] }
SELECT {
        [Measures].[Wins]
} ON COLUMNS, {
    [2015-2018-All]

} ON ROWS
FROM [Nfl2]
```

Comment: thanks, why did you put the member under the `.All` hierarchy? That is, why add it at `[Season].[Season].[All].[2015-2018]` instead of `[Season].[Season].[Season].[2015-2018]` ?

Comment: We know that attributes has two levels: All level and leaf level who holds the members like this All --> members. So if we want to add a new member we will place it under the All level like this [Season]. [Season]. [All]. [2015-2018]

Comment: sure, but why put it in the `[All]` level instead of the `[Season]` level, wouldn't both work?